# Set session attribute using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, httpsession

I'm using [jqueryui autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) in my **jsp** page. I need to set selected value of combo-box to the `HttpSession`.

I tried as below.

```
this._on(this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
        // alert(ui.item.value);
        var value = ui.item.value;
        <% session.setAttribute("comboboxvalue",value); %>  

        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
        });
}
```

Problem with this way is that code don't recognize `value` param.

How can I solve this and set session attribute using `javascript` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I achieved my task successfully.

I have created a new servlet and trigger an AJAX call as below. Then I set `comboboxvalue` to session from servlet.

```
this._on( this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'AjaxServlet',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { comboboxvalue : ui.item.value  }
        });
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
        });
    },

    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You might misunderstand that `jsp` and `javascript` existed on same file. Yes but `JSP` part compiles on server side itself comes to `client`.

The code inbetween `<%  %>`  executes on serverside.

**You can't do that with `Javascript`.**

You need to make a server request(There are forms,Ajax,url..etc) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Java script is a client side technology. Its not possible to set any session variables from Java script.

You can do this using Ajax. Through Ajax you have to send a request to the server asynchronously and then add the data to the session from within the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot set session values in JavaScript.

For your case, you can trigger an AJAX call for onChange event in your select box. You can simply send the select box value to server and place it in session.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javaScript operating form to post args to a servlet class,
and setSession in this servlet class.